# TypeError: product() got an unexpected keyword argument 'product_id'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting the fellowing error while trying to add a column to product class in sqlalchemy db by flask

**TypeError: product() got an unexpected keyword argument 'product_id'**

this is product class code:

```
class product(db.Model):
    product_id = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"product('{self.product_id}', '{self.qty}')"
```

and this is the adding code:

```
@app.route("/addProduct", methods =['GET','POST'])
def addProduct():
    form = addProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        Product = product(product_id=form.product_id.data, qty=form.qty.data)
        db.session.add(Product)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f' {form.product_id.data} Product is Added successfully!', 'success')
    return render_template('addProduct.html', form = form)
```

and it get data from a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `product` class has no `__init__()`. Did you mean this:

```py
Product = product()
Product.product_id = form.product_id.data
Product.qty = form.qty.data
```

Comment: thank you, but know it causes this error:    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'product_id' cann you help me?

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy models don't need an `__init__` method in the default configuration.   See https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/?highlight=__init__#a-minimal-application